# Question using Series Convergence or Divergence Tests

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty  \frac{((\ln(n))^n}{n!}$$

So this is the series that I have to solve for whether it is convergent or divergent in my HW, but I have been pretty stumped by it because I cannot figure out how I can solve it. If I try and use the ratio test then I can't calculate the limit. Integral and alternating series tests are also out of the question. So any idea how I should solve this?

Comment: Comparison test is always your friend.  Recall Stirling's formula.

Comment: I have never studied Stirling's formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the ratio test :
$$ \frac{(\log(n+1))^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{(\log n)^n}=\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\right)^n $$
But $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}=0$ and
$$ \begin{aligned} \left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\right)^n&=\left(1+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log n}\right)^n \\
&=\exp\left(n\log\left(1+\frac{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\log n}\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n\log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n\log n}\right)\right)\right) \\
&=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\log n}+o\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\right) \underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}1
\end{aligned} $$
Therefore $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{n+1}\left(\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}\right)^n=0$ and the series converges.